# Apache rewrite rules, how to forward url to directory but not change url address

Tags: apache

I have a site setup as:

```
mysite.com/cheese/home
mysite.com/cheese/about-us

mysite.com/fruit/home
mysite.com/fruit/about-us
```

Cheese and fruit are completely difference sites. I have two domains:

```
www.cheese.com
www.fruit.com
```

So I need to tell apache that when a user goes to `www.cheese.come` show `mysite.com/cheese/fruit` but I don't want it to redirect to there. I've  looked a lot into mod_rewrite but this doesn't appear to do what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

#### For different domains.

If you are talking about different domains, you might want a [vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) instead of a redirect or an alias. Each vhost gets another DocumentRoot.

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
 Listen 80

 # Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
 NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/cheese
 ServerName www.cheese.com
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /www/fruit
 ServerName www.fruit.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

#### For same domains:

Don't use a rewrite rule. Use an alias [see [mod_alias]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) (or a symlink).

A rewriterule sends a response to the browser, telling it to go fetch another URL. An alias just goes to find the document somewhere else, and serves it to the browser (without telling it found it somewhere else).

Aliases support regular expressions too, using the AliasMatch directive.

Comment: This is really good, I have looked into mod_alias and it works how I need it to, except that I have to map it to a folder when it needs to be to an url (Syntax: Alias URL-path file-path|directory-path) I need a way to alias a url with another url if that makes sense.

Comment: That is where vhosts come into play. You set `www.cheese.com` to your `mysite.com/cheese/home`, and `www.fruit.com` to `mysite.com/fruit/home`.

Comment: I've looked at your examples above and I still can't figure it out. How do I "set www.cheese.com to your mysite.com/cheese/home" ? Because all I can see is that it points to a directory. I might add that this is all dynamic, www/mysite/fruit does not exist in the file structure. It gets built up automatically when you access the url. Hence why I need to alias / map one url with another url.